# Can't access vector element?

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code

```
vector <int> a[100001];
a[1].push_back(1);
if( a[1][0] == 1)
      cout<<"OK!";
```

But when I try to access a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p79dG.png)[0] it says:

```
CXX0058: Error: overloaded operator not found
```

Full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
FILE *f=fopen("chei.in","r");
FILE *g=fopen("chei.out","w");
int t[100001],N,x,nr,k,d;
vector <int> a[100001];
int main(){
    fscanf(f,"%d",&N);
    for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
    { fscanf(f,"%d",&x);
      for(k=0;k<a[i].size();++k){
               if( a[i][k]== x)
                   break;}
      if(k==0 || ( k==a[x].size() && a[i][k] == x )){
              t[i]=x;
              a[x].push_back(i);
      }
    }
for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        if(t[i]==i || t[i]==0)
            nr++;}
fprintf(g,"%d",nr);
return 0;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the watch:
[image]

Comment: No offense but the fact that you need your answer fast doesn't really concern us. Actually, stating such things is likely to make people not answer at all.

Comment: (GCC compiles this fine.) Does `vector <int> &tmp (a [1]); if (tmp [0] == 1) ...` work?

Comment: I need it fast because I'm in an online contest and I have to sove a problem, but I've came against this problem... The contest ends in 1 hour, so it will help me a lot if I could solve this until then.

Comment: What is the point in attending to online contest and asking for the answers?

Comment: Is this better or worse than homework questions? I can't decide.

Comment: Contest or no contest, homework or just experimenting.. one should never mention words like "I need it fast", "please hurry up", etc. Ask the question and let the community answer at it's pace, will and capacity.

Comment: By your error code I see you're using VisualStudio, I compiled your sample with VS10 and it compiles fine, what version are you using? Also are you sure you included `vector` and `iostream`

Comment: It sounds like an error from MVC immediate interpreter. It doesn't support overloaded operators and prints such error.

Comment: The thing is, this is not what the contest asks for, it is a 100lines solving, but I keep getting this error and I really don't understand why. I'm using standard Visual Studio 2010...

Comment: Are you using some absurd STL port that doesn't work right? Does `a[1].at(0)` work?

Comment: So the two lines with a[i][k] are erroring?

Comment: Yes, a[i][k] ... a[i].at(k) doesn't work either..

Comment: can you try a vector of vectors?

Comment: @Cristy: Motti tried to compile this in VS10 and it worked for him. Could you post the version you are using and any other details so that someone might be able to reproduce your error?

Comment: The verion is 10.0.30319.1 RMTRel.

Comment: Seems like a[1].(1) works? Why's that ?:))

Comment: On VS2008 it compiles fine, but I get a `stack overflow` error in run-time, probably due to too large an array - with 10,000 elements instead of 100,000 it works fine.

Comment: Okay, what's your build configuration? Debug Win32? Are you using any weird project settings? It seems to work just fine for other people.

Comment: The array needs to be 100.000, it only uses like 400kb.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Debug, Win32

Comment: vector< vector< int > > would be better and what makes you think a[x] is valid? x may be > 100000 or negative?

Comment: X is an integer bewteen 1 and 100.000

Comment: It seems that, when I've send the .cpp to a server, it worked well(i guess), I don't know why am I getting this error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. Nearly everyone thought you meant a compile error, but ybungalobill pointed out that retrieving the results of the operator are just not supported by visual studio's debugger.

This isn't anything to worry about if your program does what you expect it to do. Your program can access the vector element just fine, even if your debugger is a bit confused.

To allow your debugger to report the value, try setting the watch like so: `((a[1])._Myfirst)[0]`
as per the recommendation in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/c09f4fe4-4783-4dbb-8d36-85489fa2a4ae

Comment: The thing is, it's not working well, it reaches all the way to the return 0; and then it stops (doesn't complete the execution)

Comment: It finishes for me. Though, admittedly I don't have an input file, it just prints 0 to the output file and exits. Also, good to hear that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with g++ compiler and the code works fine.

What compiler are you using?

Comment: The one that comes with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 should support this piece of code unless there are some kind of new standard that makes vector element access like this obsolete. Do you have "a" declared somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some absurd STL port that doesn't work right? Try `a[1].at(0)`.

Comment: a[1].at(0) returns CXX0039: Error: symbol is ambiguous

Comment: Can you post the full code? With all the irrelevant parts trimmed, but able to compile?